# How can I refine a `mixed` to a `T[]`?

Tags: flowtype

Say I have some `x: mixed` and I want to refine this to `string[]`, throwing an error otherwise.

It's obvious how to refine this to an *array* (`Array.isArray(x)`); but how can I get Flow to understand that this is an array where *every element* is of type `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it without `any` requires making a new array, e.g.

```
function toStringArray(vals: mixed): Array<string> {
  if (!Array.isArray(vals)) throw new Error("...");

  return vals.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (typeof item !== "string") throw new Error("...");
    acc.push(item);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

which should be relatively self-explanatory.

If you for some reason you absolutely needed to return the same array, you can also use `any`, e.g.

```
function toStringArrayIdent(vals: mixed): Array<string> {
  if (!Array.isArray(vals)) throw new Error("...");

  vals.forEach(item => {
    if (typeof item !== "string") throw new Error("...");
  });

  return (vals: any);
}
```

but this has the downside that Flow can't fully guaranteed things of `vals` was changed again later, e.g.

```
var vals: mixed = ['one', 'two'];
var strs = toStringArrayIdent(vals);

if (Array.isArray(vals)) vals.push(4);
```

will not error even though it is pushing a `number`.